# Finance Manager with Embedded Database

Tags: java, beginner, javafx, crud

I made an CRUD application in Java with JavaFX, H2 Embedded Database and Maven. Can you review my code quickly? Is it well written? What should I improve on it? I don't know if my code is written correctly, I'm a beginner in Java programming and I'm looking for advices. Where should I look for reviews of my code?

For more information, see [the github repository](https://github.com/damianlebiedz/Finance-Manager-CRUD-)

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/MainView.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 1080, 720);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("/css/style.css")).toExternalForm());
            Image icon = new Image(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/icon.png")));
            stage.getIcons().add(icon);
            stage.setTitle("Finance Manager");
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Data {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String category;
    private final float price;
    private final String date;
}
```

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField total;
    @FXML
    private TextField search;
    @FXML
    private TextField errorField;

    @FXML
    private TextField nameField;
    @FXML
    private MenuButton categoryField;
    @FXML
    private TextField priceField;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker dateField;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Data> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> nameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> categoryColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, Float> priceColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, Date> dateColumn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        showData();
        dateField.setValue(LocalDate.now());
    }
    @FXML
    private void addBtn() {
        try {
            if(categoryField.getText().equals("Select a category")) {
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            }
            String query =
                    "INSERT INTO DATA VALUES (default,'" + nameField.getText() + "','" + categoryField.getText() +
                            "'," + Float.parseFloat(priceField.getText()) + ",'" + dateField.getValue().toString() +
                            "')";
            executeUpdate(query);
            showData();
            errorField.clear();
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            errorField.setText("INCORRECT DATA");
        }
    }
    @FXML
    private void deleteBtn() {
        Data data = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        int id = data.getId();
        String query =
                "DELETE FROM DATA WHERE ID="+id+";";
        executeUpdate(query);
        showData();
    }
    @FXML
    private void updateBtn() {
        try {
            if(categoryField.getText().equals("Select a category") || priceField.getText().startsWith("0")) {
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            }
            Data data = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            int id = data.getId();
            String query =
                    "UPDATE  DATA SET NAME ='" + nameField.getText() + "', CATEGORY = '" + categoryField.getText() + "'," + " PRICE = " +
                            Float.parseFloat(priceField.getText()) + ", DATE = '" + dateField.getValue().toString() + "' " +
                            "WHERE id = " + id + "";
            executeUpdate(query);
            showData();
            errorField.clear();
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            errorField.setText("INCORRECT DATA");
        }
    }
    @FXML
    private void onMouseClickedTable() {
        try {
            Data data = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            nameField.setText(data.getName());
            categoryField.setText(data.getCategory());
            priceField.setText(String.valueOf(data.getPrice()));
            dateField.setValue(LocalDate.parse(data.getDate()));
        }
        catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
        }
    }
    @FXML
    private void category(ActionEvent event) {
        String category = ((MenuItem) event.getSource()).getText();
        switch (category) {
            case "food" -> categoryField.setText("food");
            case "cosmetics" -> categoryField.setText("cosmetics");
            case "medicines" -> categoryField.setText("medicines");
            case "bills" -> categoryField.setText("bills");
            case "other" -> categoryField.setText("other");
        }
    }
    private ObservableList<Data> getDataList() {
        ObservableList<Data> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        DBConnection DBConnection = new DBConnection();
        Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DATA");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            while (result.next()) {
                dataList.add(new Data(
                        result.getInt("id"),
                        result.getString("name"),
                        result.getString("category"),
                        result.getFloat("price"),
                        result.getString("date"))
                );
            }
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataList;
    }
    private void showData() {
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        categoryColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("category"));
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        priceColumn.setCellFactory(price -> new TableCell<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Float aFloat, boolean b) {
                super.updateItem(aFloat, b);
                if (aFloat == null || b) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(String.format("%.2f", aFloat));
                }
            }
        });

        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));

        searchData();
        dateColumn.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
        table.getSortOrder().add(dateColumn);
        table.sort();
    }
    private void executeUpdate(String query) {
        try {
            DBConnection DBConnection = new DBConnection();
            Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.executeUpdate();

            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void searchData() {
        FilteredList<Data> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(getDataList(), b -> true);
        search.textProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> filteredData.setPredicate(Data -> {
            if(newValue.isEmpty() || newValue.isBlank()) {
                return true;
            }
            String lowerCase = newValue.toLowerCase();

            if(Data.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else if(Data.getCategory().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else if(String.valueOf(Data.getPrice()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else return String.valueOf(Data.getDate()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase);
        }));
        SortedList<Data> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
        table.setItems(sortedData);

        sortedData.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Data> c) -> setTotal());
        setTotal();
    }
    private void setTotal() {
        float totalAmount = 0;
        totalAmount = table.getItems().stream().map(
                Data::getPrice).reduce(totalAmount, Float::sum);
        total.setText("Total: "+String.format("%.2f", totalAmount));
    }
}
```

```
public class DBConnection {
    String url = "jdbc:h2:./src/main/resources/db/data";
    String username = "sa";
    String password = "123";

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks nice. Do you host this project, say, on GitHub where reviewers can access the icon PNG among other resources?

Comment: Also, it would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about the code in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"

Comment: Yes, you can find it here: https://github.com/damianlebiedz/Finance-Manager-CRUD-

Comment: Is there anything to improve here?

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/286756/revisions#rev-body-6fc791bf-3db7-40f2-b3bb-e4de1622cb56) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: I like the answer, but I would add separate your DB logic. You did create `DBConnection `, but I think it should be `DBHandler`. I think it should handle all logic associated with the DB, not just the connection.

Answer (score 2):

## accurate to the penny

```
public class Data {
    ...
    private final float price;
```

Consider representing that as a
[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)
scaled integer, to avoid
[FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Character_representation)
rounding issues.
Representing a dollar-twenty as
`1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`
seems a regrettable choice.
Suppose someone's account has thirty cents,
and we spend twenty cents and then a dime: `.3 - .2 - .1`
The account balance has gone negative!
We can do better.

Postgres and many relational databases offer scaled integer support
via the NUMERIC sql keyword.
H2's DECIMAL [documentation](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#numeric_type)
specifically calls out:

> This data type is recommended for storing currency values.

and explains that what you chose
"should not be used to represent currency values, because of rounding problems."

Alternatively you might elect to represent `price`
as an `Integer` number of pennies.

```
    private final String date;
```

Another odd choice, but I imagine you have your reasons
for preferring VARCHAR over DATE.
As long as you stick with an
[ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179)
representation the lexical ordering will work out OK.

---

## manifest constants

```
    public void start(Stage stage) {
            ...
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 1080, 720);
```

Please give names to those
[magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)),
perhaps `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`.

---

## production SQL

```
            String query =
                    "INSERT INTO DATA VALUES (default,'" + nameField.getText() + "','" + categoryField.getText() +
                            "'," + Float.parseFloat(priceField.getText()) + ",'" + dateField.getValue().toString() +
                            "')";
```

I would have called it `String insert`
since it's not a SELECT `query`,
but fine, we'll let that detail slide.

This INSERT is fine for interactive data exploration.
But please name the columns when you put it into production.

Why?
Sooner or later the table schema will change.
Columns get re-ordered, or new ones are added.
We want that to trigger an error here rather than silently defaulting.
And we want Author's Intent to be crystal clear
to that poor maintenance engineer who will revisit
this statement a few months down the road.

---

## swallowing exceptions

```
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ...
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Not the worst bit of java code that I've ever seen.
But it doesn't seem especially helpful.
Consider re-throwing: `throw new RuntimeException(e);`

```
    private ObservableList<Data> getDataList() {
        ObservableList<Data> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ...
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataList;
```

The callers, `showData()` and `searchData()`,
have no idea that the zero-length return value
corresponds to an error rather than truth stored in a table.
There is no way for a caller to correctly fulfill its
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

Rather than swallowing an exception,
this code really ought to be letting it propagate up the call stack.
Either someone will know how to deal with it,
or we (correctly) will display a stack trace.

Similar craziness happens in `executeUpdate()`.

In `getDataList()` we potentially assign `Connection connection = null`
and then NPE on `connection.prepareStatement()`,
mixing that NPE in with the various other kinds of errors a SELECT might generate.

---

## nouns for names

```
            else if(Data.getCategory().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
```

Here we're essentially comparing against `lowerCaseNewValue` or perhaps `lcNewValue`.
The adjective identifier turned out to not be very convenient.
Consider putting the long name up front:

```
        ... .addListener((..., ..., mixedNewValue) -> ... -> { ...
            String newValue = mixedNewValue.toLowerCase();
```

Downcasing `price` seems a curious operation,
unless you really want to keep it as FP
and are concerned about uppercase `E` appearing in scientific notation.

Downcasing `date` suggests that you're *not* using an ISO 8601 representation.
You might want to revisit that decision.

Also, please write one sentence of `/** javadoc */`
for `searchData()`, explaining
[what it does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).
I'm sure there's a good reason for `"  "` (two blanks)
acting as a match-all wildcard; I just haven't quite seen it, yet.

---

## automated testing

I see no unit tests at
https://github.com/damianlebiedz/Finance-Manager-CRUD-/tree/main/src .
Spotting regressions as they're committed
will prove valuable to you as this small project evolves into a larger one.

---

This codebase appears to achieve many of its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.